# Rgeo geom nil on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgis, postgresql-9.3, rgeo

I've got a really weird bug that I hope someone here can help with. I've imported a shape file into my rails postgis database. It contains the following columns:

- search
- source
- search2
- dups
- geom

The geom column contains an RGeo MultiPolygon coordinate.

What's weird is my local rails application has no problem reading all of the records geom fields, but my production server has a few records that have nil in the geom field.

Both applications have the exact same code in git and are looking at the exact same database.

The only difference between the two apps is my local is running on a OSX while the production is running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is some code snippets to help diagnose the problem:

**config/database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  database: coflood_production
  host: opensource1
  port: 5432
  pool: 5
  username: xxxxxxx (hidden)
  password: xxxxxxx (hidden)
```

**app/models/gazetteer.rb**

```
class Gazetteer < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'gazetteer'
  self.primary_key = 'gid'

  attr_accessible :geom, :search, :search2, :source
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter', '0.6.5'
gem 'devise', '3.2.2'
gem 'rgeo-geojson', '0.2.3'
gem 'js-routes', '0.9.6'
gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  gem "therubyracer", '0.12.0'
  gem "less-rails", '2.4.2'  #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", '2.2.8'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
```

If you can think of anything else that would be useful, just let me know and I'll provide it asap.

### Update 1

So there are differences in how I've installed postgresql and postgis on both systems. On OSX (local), I've installed the opengeo software suite that included all the components I needed. On Ubuntu (production), I installed postgresql-9.3 using apt-get.

Thanks to a comment here, I noticed that I had not installed a few things like geos and gdal on the production server. I installed both and unfortunately still have the same error.

### Update 2

So I decided to try to get the production server as close to the same environment as my local machine to see if that would fix my issue. I removed the apt installations of postgres/postgis/geos and installed the Ubuntu opengeo software suite. This is what I am using on my local machine.

Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.

I then noticed I was using different version of ruby. So I updated my production server to use the same version (ruby 2.0.0p247).

Still did not solve the error.

I am still completely bewildered by this bug. It seems like this must have something to do with rails, rgeo, or activerecord-postgis-adapter gems.

### Update 3

So I noticed there are differences between the records that do come up with geometry on both systems. I looked at the first record in the database and both had geometry in the geom field, but the Rgeo type was different between the platforms.

**Local Server (OSX)**

RGeo::Geos::CAPIMultiPolygonImpl:0x3fc7af864fdc "MULTIPOLYGON ..."

**Production Server (Ubuntu 12.04)**

RGeo::Geographic::SphericalMultiPolygonImpl:0x1b07a4c "MULTIPOLYGON ..."

It seems like it is failing at converting the RGeo::Geographic object into a RGeo::Geos coordinate.

Comment: Are you sure rgeo is installed on your production server? Try RGeo::Geos.supported? in irb on your server.

Comment: It returns false on my production server and true on my local. I'm installing geos on the production server to see if this fixes the problem. You get major props if this works!

Comment: Well after installing Geos, that command now returns true on the production server. Unfortunately the same records still show geom as nil. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have had similar issues where different machines would produce different results for the same geojson data for no apparent reason. I tinkered a bit and discovered that it had something to do with features which contain too many polygons, but that is about as far as I got. Did you ever figure this one out? I'd love to hear any more insight if you have some.